# Arel::Table @aliases memory leak when used in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-leaks, arel

One sentence summary question: What would cause `Arel::Table`'s `@aliases` array to grow in size for every search done using ActiveRecord?

I have written a simple web application using Rails 5. When I load tested it, memory usage increased indefinitely. After 2.2 million requests, the process was up to about 1GB of resident memory size.

I investigated by getting heap dumps before, right after, and 10 minutes after executing a load test with 100,000 requests. I analyzed the heap dumps using [the heap dump diffing tool found here](http://blog.skylight.io/hunting-for-leaks-in-ruby/). It says that there were about 398,000 leaked objects created by [`Arel::Table#alias()`](https://github.com/rails/arel/blob/master/lib/arel/table.rb#L30).

This statement seems to be the culprit:

```
@aliases << node
```

I confirmed that `Arel::Table`'s `@aliases` array is the source of the memory leak by adding a call to `uniq!` in my installed version of `Arel::Table#alias()`:

```
def alias name = "#{self.name}_2"
  Nodes::TableAlias.new(self, name).tap do |node|
    @aliases << node
  end
  @aliases.uniq! # locally added this line
end
```

With this modification to Arel, my app's memory usage remained flat for the duration of the load test.

As far as I can tell, `@aliases` grows with every request to my app, and it grows with identical objects. I am wondering whether this is a bug in Arel or I am doing something bad in my app to cause this array to grow without ever being cleared or garbage collected.

The app has four models:

**Models**

```
class DeviceVendor < ApplicationRecord
end

class Group < ApplicationRecord
end

class RadiusDevice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :device_vendor
  validates :ipv4_address, :ip => {format: :v4}
end

class RadiusVsa < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :device_vendor
end
```

**Migrations**

```
class CreateGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :groups do |t|
      t.string :dn
      t.integer :rank

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateDeviceVendors < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :device_vendors do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateRadiusDevices < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :radius_devices do |t|
      t.string :ipv4_address
      t.string :model_number
      t.belongs_to :device_vendor, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateRadiusVsas < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :radius_vsas do |t|
      t.string :radius_attributes
      t.belongs_to :device_vendor, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :group, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end

  end
end
```

My only HTTP endpoint searches for `RadiusVsa` based on input parameters for `Group.dn` and `RadiusDevice.ipv4_address`. Here are the ActiveRecord calls involved:

```
# groups param value is like: ['ou=foo,cn=bar', 'ou=baz,cn=qux']
group = Group.order(rank: :desc).find_by!(dn: params.require('groups'))
# source param value is like: '10.0.0.1'
radius_device = RadiusDevice.find_by!(ipv4_address: params.require('source'))
# RadiusVsa.find_by! is the call that causes Arel::Table#alias() to be invoked
vendor_attributes = RadiusVsa.find_by!(group: group, device_vendor: radius_device.device_vendor)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this memory leak is a bug in Arel. After getting no responses here for a day we created [an issue in Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26481) which has now been fixed.